# When is it best to use a class in Python?

Tags: python, oop, class, function

I'm new to python and programming in general, so would really appreciate any clarification on this point.

For example, in the following code:

```
    #Using a class
class Monster(object): 
    def __init__(self, level, damage, duration): 
        print self
        self.level = level
        self.damage = damage
        self.duration = duration

    def fight(self):
        print self 
        print "The monster's level is ", self.level
        print "The monster's damage is ", self.damage
        print "The attack duration is ", self.duration

    def sleep(self): 
        print "The monster is tired and decides to rest."

x = Monster(1, 2, 3)
y = Monster(2, 3, 4)
x.fight()
y.fight()
    y.sleep() 

   #just using a function
def fight_func(level, damage, duration):
    print "The monster's level is ", level
    print "The monster's damage is ", damage
    print "The attack duration is ", duration

fight_func(1, 2, 3)
fight_func(5,3,4)
```

The pure function version seems cleaner and gives the same result.

Is the primary value of classes that you can create and call a number of methods on an object, e.g. fight or sleep?

Comment: This might help. It's the [wikipedia article on cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)#Types_of_cohesion).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your example is rather simplified.

In a more complete example fighting wouldn't just display the current state - it would also modify that state. Your monster might get hurt and that would change its hit points and morale. This state has to be stored somewhere. If you use a class it would be natural to add instance variables to store this state.

Using only functions it would be more difficult to find a good place to store the state.

Comment: read this for more insight: http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html

Comment: @Yoel: while I recommend perusal of SICP to anyone interesting in computing, I hardly see its value in this case. It teaches a functional programming style, not OOP.

Comment: Mark is suggesting that if the fight_func needs to track state about the fight, then creating a fight manager class that keeps the fight state internally would be a good idea.  On the other hand, if the only state is the damage being done to the monsters, then you don't really need it.

Comment: yes, but it does tackle the issue that @MarkByers and OP were getting at, about how state works in programming, functional and oop

Comment: @larsmans also Python is a functional programming language too http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html

Comment: @Yoel Python has some facilities intended for functional use, but calling it a functional language is something of a stretch.

Comment: ...I do agree that spending some time doing functional programming is useful -- decoupling the concepts of state and identity can certainly lead to clearer thinking and better designs even if one doesn't end up using a functional language in the long run -- but I also have to agree that it isn't directly on-point here.

Comment: Thank you, @Mark Byers. Would you please provide an example of adding instance variables to store a changed state? It would be very helpful to me. I tried to create a simple example in order to work out the most basic use-case scenario, though I can see that it might not be the best example to have used.

Comment: @user1186742: In the `__init__` method you could write `self.hitpoints = 10` and then in your `fight` method you might write `self.hitpoints -= 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Your example isn't particularly interesting — it just prints three numbers.  You don't need classes, or even a function (really) to do that.

But if you ever need to write a program that has to keep track of two separate monsters at one time, know their health, differentiate their fighting abilities, and so, you can see the value of encapsulating each of the monsters in a separate monster instance.

Comment: I think I'll have to come back later with a better example. Thank you for your explanation - it's starting to make sense to me now. :)

Answer (score 2):

what about my monsters? he can fight another monster! Presumably your functional monster cannot do that ;-)

```
class Monster(object): 
    def __init__(self, level, damage, duration): 
        self.level    = level
        self.damage   = damage
        self.duration = duration
    def fight(self, enemy):
        if not isinstance(enemy, Monster) :
            print "The enemy is not a monster, so I can't fight it."
            return None
        else :
            print "Starting fighting"
        print "My monster's level is ", self.level
        print "My monster's damage is ", self.damage
        print "My monster's attack duration is ", self.duration
        print "The enemy's level is ", enemy.level
        print "The enemy's damage is ", enemy.damage
        print "The enemy's attack duration is ", enemy.duration

        result_of_fight = 3.*(self.level    - enemy.level)  + \
                          2.*(self.damage   - enemy.damage) + \
                          1.*(self.duration - enemy.duration)
        if result_of_fight > 0 :
            print "My monster wins the brutal battle"
        elif result_of_fight < 0 :
            print "My monster is defeated by the enemy"
        else :
            print "The two monsters both retreat for a draw"
        return result_of_fight
    def sleep(self, days): 
        print "The monster is tired and decides to rest for %3d days" % days
        self.level    += 3.0 * days
        self.damage   += 2.0 * days
        self.duration += 2.0 * days
x = Monster(1, 2, 3)
y = Monster(2, 3, 4)
x.fight(y)
x.sleep(10)
```

so:

```
Starting fighting
My monster's level is  1
My monster's damage is  2
My monster's attack duration is  3
The enemy's level is  2
The enemy's damage is  3
The enemy's attack duration is  4
My monster is defeated by the enemy
The monster is tired and decides to rest for  10 days
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for sharing a more fleshed-out example. Super helpful to read through. I'm unfamiliar with the %3d format. Why did you use that rather than just %d?

Comment: the `%3d` was a bit of nuance, it only impose a 3 digit inimum field width, so that multiple outputs for `days` below `1000` will be aligned.

Comment: Hm, okay. Thank you. One more question, if you're willing: Why did you decide to multiply the result of the subtraction operation in this code block?  `result_of_fight = 3.*(self.level    - enemy.level)  + \ 2.*(self.damage   - enemy.damage) + \ 1.*(self.duration - enemy.duration)`

Comment: ah, that was nuisance and arbitrary as well. I want to put progressively more weights on duration, damage, and level for determining the result of fight.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general answer than for just your code, but classes are useful when you need to:

- **Share state safely across specific functions**.

  Classes offer encapsulation to avoid polluting the global namespace
  with variables that only need to be shared across a few functions. You don't want someone using your code to overwrite a variable all of your functions are using - you always want to be able to control access as much as possible.

  Classes can be instantiated and have multiple independent *copies* of the same variable that are not shared at all while requiring very little code use.

  They're appropriate when you need to model interactions between a *collection* of functions and variables with another collection of functions and variables i.e. when you need to model objects. Defining a class for a single function with no state is frankly a waste of code.
- **Provide operator overloading or define specific traits for certain types**

  What makes `int`, `string`, and `tuples` hashable (can be used as keys in a dictionary or inserted into a `set`), while `list`s and `dict`s aren't?

  Answer: the *base classes* for these primitive types implement the [magic method](http://www.diveintopython3.net/special-method-names.html) `__hash__`, which enables the Python compiler to dynamically compute a hash at runtime.

  What allows the `+` operator to be overloaded, so that `5 + 2 = 7` for `int`s but `'s' + 'a' = 'sa'` for strings?

  Answer: the *base classes* for these types defines their own `__add__` method, which lets you define exactly how addition between two members of your class is carried out.

  All user-defined classes can implement these methods. There are good use cases for them: larger mathematical libraries - numpy, scipy, and pandas - make heavy use of operator overloading by defining these magic methods to provide you useful objects to handle your data. Classes are the only way to implement these traits and properties in Python.

Classes are not superior to functions when the above conditions are not met.

Use a class to *group together* meaningful functions and variables in a sensible way, or to endow your objects with special properties. Anything else is superfluous.